# Javascript substr( ) inconsistent

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to write a function that takes in a string of form 'X:XX PM' and change it into a 24HR time string without the AM or PM.

This means:

'12:00 AM' becomes '00:00'

'3:30 AM' becomes '03:30'

'4:00 PM' becomes '16:00'

'12:30 PM' becomes '12:30'

and so on.

I'm using Javascript's substr() function, and it seems to be working inconsistently. Here's the code:

```
function unFormatTime( timeString ) {
console.log( "length: " + timeString.length );
console.log( "string passed in: " + timeString );
var hour = 0;
var minute = '';
var amOrPm = '';

if ( length == 7 ) {
    hour = parseInt( timeString.substr( 0, 1 ) );
    minute = timeString.substr( 2, 2 );
    amOrPm = timeString.substr( 5, 2 );
} else {
    hour = parseInt( timeString.substr( 0, 2 ) );
    minute = timeString.substr( 3, 2 );
    amOrPm = timeString.substr( 6, 2 );
}
for ( var i = 0; i < timeString.length; i++ ) {
    console.log( i + ", 1 " + "'" + timeString.substr( i, 1 ) + "'" );
    console.log( i + ", 2 " + "'" + timeString.substr( i, 2 ) + "'" );
}

console.log( "unparsed: " + hour + " " + "'" + minute + "'" + " " + "'" + amOrPm + "'" );

if ( amOrPm == "PM" ) {
    if ( hour != 12 ) {
        hour += 12;
    }
} else {
    if ( hour == 12 ) {
        hour -= 12;
    }
}

if ( hour < 10 ) {
    hour = '0' + hour;
}
console.log( "parsed: " + hour + " " + minute + " " + "'" + amOrPm + "'" );

var newString = hour + ':' + minute;
console.log( newString );
return newString;
```

}

That loop is there because substr is being wonky. When the function is given '4:00 AM', the loop will print

```
0, 1 '4'
2, 2 '00'
5, 2 'AM'
```

These being the matching substrings assigned to hour, minute and amOrPm when the string's length is 7. When I print those actual variables however, I get:

```
unparsed: 4 '0 ' 'M'
```

So the minute and amOrPm values are somehow not being set correctly. I'm sure I just have a typo somewhere, but right now it seems like some kind of bug in Javascript and it's driving me crazy.

Comment: Not necessarily related to your problem but: http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/ :)

Comment: Is there a reason you wouldn't try to use the Date API and then some sort of date parsing?  http://momentjs.com/ would be a good resource for this.

Comment: There isn't a good reason, and if I can't figure this out I'll look into that. I started with substr because what I'm doing is pretty simple and I know how to use it already. Now it's more a matter of understanding why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I notice is

```
if ( length == 7 )
```

Should be

```
if ( timeString.length == 7 )
```

When I make that change and execute the function with `4:00 AM` as an argument, I get the following:

```
unparsed: 4 '00' 'AM'
parsed: 04 00 'AM'
04:00
```

Seems legit? Although I would recommend using regular expressions for this sort of task.

Comment: Aw geez, I knew it was something like this. Especially since double digit houred times were working fine. length was undefined so it was never getting to the first code block. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I'd have not approached this with the substr method. If you wanted to tackled this sans-external library then the vanilla approach I'd take is splitting the string based on the ":" and the " ".  This is coffeescript but you get the idea:

```
times = [
  '12:00 AM'
  '3:30 AM'
  '4:00 PM'
  '12:30 PM'
]

converted = []

isPm = (s)-> s?.toLowerCase() is 'pm'

for t in times
  [hr, min] = t.split ':'
  [min, amPm] = min.split ' '

  if hr is '12' and !isPm(amPm)
    hr = '00'

  else if hr isnt '12' and isPm(amPm)
    hr = parseInt(hr) + 12

  if hr.toString().length < 2
    hr = "0" + hr

  converted.push "#{hr}:#{min}"

console.log converted # ["00:00", "03:30", "16:00", "12:30"]
```

I'm sure there is a regexp way of doing this, I just didn't look to deeply because I am usually using an external library like moment.js to do date calculations and date string parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing things could be (and obviously this has edge cases not handled and validation is not done):

```
function parse(input){
  if (!input) return "";

  var isPM = /pm/i.test(input); // check if pm is in the string
  var time = input.replace(/(a|p)m/ig, ''); // remove am/pm
  time = input.replace(' ', ''); // remove spaces

  var timeParts = time.split(':');

  var hour = parseInt(timeParts[0], 10);
  var minute = parseInt(timeParts[1], 10);

  if(isPM) { hour+=12; }
  else if (hour === 12){hour = 0}

  // transform single digit numbers to double digits: 2 to 02
  return ('00' + hour).slice(-2) + ':' + ('00' + minute).slice(-2);
}
```

I find your solution a bit difficult to follow.